# drools RHS is not evaluating properly

Tags: dynamic, conditional-statements, drools

I have a POJO defined as below

```
public MyClass{
String batchId
String id;
List<Cols> cols;
}

public Cols {
BigDecimal colA;
BigDecimal colB;
BigDecimal colC;
}
```

Now I have drools rule as below

```
rule "myrule"
when
$f : MyClass() //full
$v : Cols(batchId!=null) from $f.cols
$h : Cols(batchId!=null && func(colaA, colB, colC, true)) from $f.cols //subset of $v with additional constraints
then
$f.addResults("myrule",$v, $h)
end
```

"myrule" is compiling and executing IFF  $h is having a value generated. What I need is if there is non-null $v then it should execute then always with $h being optional..

This use case is for a data quality application where we are trying to identify whether that rule should be run for a fact first and if its a valid facts (batchId is NOT NULL) then validate expression in $h. If $h is not there then $v is treated as a PASS. If $h is NOT NULL then $v is treated as FAIL and corresponding result is added to $f (fact level).

When I run that case, rule is executing and adding results only if there $h is NOT NULL.

How can add results for $v even if there is no $h?

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem is. According to your use case, if $h is not null, then $v is a fail and you call addResults. If $h _is_ null, it's not a fail, and the rule doesn't fire. That sounds correct to me and it matches what you've implemented.

Comment: Also there's no way your rule is compiling and executing because you're trying to check for the value of batchId on the Cols class, which has no such variable or method defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your POJO doesn't match your rule, and neither match your use case, so I have no idea what you're actually doing.

But if I understand you correctly, you need your rule to trigger regardless of the presence of `$h`, though the `$h` is actually needed on the right hand side.

To do this, you need two rules. One for when `$h` does exist, and one for when `$h` does not.

For when `$h` does exist, your existing rule works fine. Or, it will work fine if your POJO is updated to match your rule or your rule is updated to match your POJO. (Your rule is checking that batchId on your Cols class is null; there is no batchId on your Cols class.)

The second rule would be when there is no `$h`. Since I have no idea what your `addResults` method is or how it's implemented, I'm presuming you'd pass a null or empty list in place of the `$h` variable to that method. You can check that there is no `$h` by using the `not(...)` expression on the left hand side.

---

Using your POJO's and ignoring the rule you did provide, I would implement this as follows:

```
// This is the existing rule, updated to match the POJO
rule "myrule with $h"
when
  $f: MyClass( batchId != null, // batchId is on MyClass, not Cols
               $v: cols != null )
  
  // Per the comments, $h is supposed to be a subset of $v
  // The "additional constraints" are implemented as a not-null check for demo purposes
  $h: List(size > 0) from collect(Cols( colA != null, colB != null, colC != null ) from $v) 
then
  $f.addResult("myrule", $v, $h);
end

rule "myrule with no $h"
when
  $f: MyClass( batchId != null,
               $v: cols != null )

  // check that there are no Cols that match the additional constraint inside of $v
  not( Cols( colA != null, colB != null, colC != null ) from $v)
then
  // set an empty list as $h in the addResults method
  $f.addResult("myrule", $v, Collections.emptyList());
end
```